# Unresolved Reference: findViewById in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun Tryouts() {
var CheckBox1 : CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.ForwardBox) as CheckBox
CheckBox1.setChecked(false)
}
```

I'm still a beginner in Kotlin having learnt only the basic working of kotlin, I am unable refer to any android widget or change it's state in Android Studio whether it's TextView or CheckBox or RadioBox.
Same Unresolved Reference errors for findViewById in all cases...
I don't know what is it that I am doing wrong, even java conversion outputs the same errors.

Comment: As a side note I'd recommend taking a look at [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), eliminates the need for `findViewById()`

Answer (score 15):

It seems this is the easiest way to get rid of `findViewById ()`

Go to your Build.Gradle (Module: app)

Add the following line

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

- Then it will ask you to sync
- Then press sync

After that come to your Activity file Say it many be `MainActivity.kt`

There import 
To import single view

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout_name>.<view_name>;
```

or

To import all views

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout_name>.*;
```

Example :
in your Layout

```
<Checkbox id="@+/forwardBox" . .  . />
```

it is in `activity_main` layout
then import as

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.forwardBox;
```

so either in your function or class use it directly

```
forwardBox.isChecked = false
```

Comment: 'kotlin-android-extensions' is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin you do not need to use `findViewById`, Simply use id `ForwardBox` from `kotlinx.android.synthetic.<your layout name>`. All used elements in your code gets automatically found and assigned to same variable name as ids in layout(xml) by kotlin.

For example:

```
fun init(){
    ForwardBox.isChecked = false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this `val CheckBox1 = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.ForwardBox)` for newer versions of android studios

Answer (score 2):

```
fun Tryouts() {
    val checkBox = findViewById(R.id.ForwardBox) as CheckBox
    checkBox.isChecked = false
}
```

Anyway, consider to define your IDs in lowercase separed by underscores, for instance:

```
val checkBox = findViewById(R.id.forward_box) as CheckBox
```

Comment: I guess **val** is even better in this case

Comment: Well, this does not answer the OP's question: unresolved reference errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced exactly the same issue, the problem is they have upgraded everything to view binding ,
Try to use it as a private function inside your main class
`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()` - there it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem, the cause was that I accidentally declared the function outside the class, where the findViewById method from AppCompatActivity is not available.

Moved it back into the scope of the class and the referenced resolved.

Answer (score 0):

am an android newbie for me the below change resolved the issue.

`var CheckBox1 = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.ForwardBox)`

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of kotlin and/or android studio, I just did:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

(at the top of the build.gradle [Module] file)

Then I returned to my activity code and wrote my button name (btn_search) and android studio got the reference done

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong. Please change it to this.

```
fun Tryouts() {
    var CheckBox1 = findViewById(R.id.ForwardBox) as CheckBox
    CheckBox1.setChecked(false)
}
```

In Kotlin, just declare a variable. Like: `var abc`

**abc** can be initialized by any type of object.

If we have to take a view from layout then we have to write:

```
findViewById(R.id.ForwardBox)
```

Then cast that view.

```
findViewById(R.id.ForwardBox) as CheckBox
```

Then store in a variable.

```
var CheckBox1 = findViewById(R.id.ForwardBox) as CheckBox
```

Comment: Do not say "your code is wrong", if it wasn't the question wouldn't exist. Say something useful instead, like why it's wrong.