# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, kotlin

I know this has been asked many times but i am really not able to understand why I am not able to add Floating Action Button in one of the fragments of TabLayout.

It is giving me error as 'kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton' in my logcat.

I am new to android and app development and really appreciate help here as I have already wasted my 3 days

MainActivity Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val fab = findViewById<View>(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    initToolbar()


    val tabLayout: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)

    val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)

    val adapter = SampleAdapter(supportFragmentManager)


    viewPager.adapter = adapter



    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : 
 TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
    })


    }

  private fun initToolbar() {
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.title = "Don't Forget"
  }
  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

logcat:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.ashwinis.mylistapp/com.ashwinis.mylistapp.MainActivity}: 
  kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type 
  android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type 
 android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 at com.ashwinis.mylistapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
 at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="FragmentOne" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

Comment: In your layout `activity_main.xml` is no item with the id `fab`, and you get a null pointer at `val fab = findViewById<View>(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton` because fab is null.

Comment: If you're new to android/kotlin, you might want to learn [kotlin android extension plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to get rid of findViewById calls.

Comment: @Pawel: Added your suggestion to OP in my answer.

Comment: Sorry..I missed to mention that I need to add Floating Action button to only one fragment 'fragment_one'. Adding 'fragment_one.xml'

Comment: @AshS Then you should bind the `fragment_one.xml` to your fragment class and instantiate the fab button and its function there.

Comment: Tried to initiate fab button in fragment class but its giving errror 'Unresolved reference 'findViewById' .

Comment: @AshS Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181485/unresolved-reference-findviewbyid-in-kotlin) regarding the `Unresolved reference 'findViewById`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `FloatingActionButton` in your xml with id `fab` which is causing it to be null.

Also, when casting something that could be null to a type which is non-null (here FloatingActionButton) you need to use `?`

Try

```
val fab = findViewById<View>(R.id.fab) as? FloatingActionButton
```

For more information read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator

**EDIT**

@Pawel's comment is really helpful. Read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html to get rid of `findViewById` calls which is the main reason of NPE.